# viewWillDisappear gets called with Cmd+W but never with Cmd+Q for Mac App made in Swift

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa

I am building a simple single window app using Swift on Xcode (using storyboard) where I display data from a BLE device. The BLE device is given a command to switch on certain sensors by the app, and the data can be seen using the app. While exiting, I need the application to ask the BLE device to switch off the sensors.

For this purpose, I overloaded the function viewWillDisappear in ViewController.swift and performed the BLE commands needed there. I can see that if I close the window, my BLE device switches off it's sensors and goes to sleep.

But, when I simply press Cmd+Q or "Exit" from the menu, the app exits without performing the viewWillDisappear function! Is the Cmd+Q supposed to be an ungraceful exit?

How do I make sure that the "viewWillDisappear" function gets called on Cmd+Q too? Or, is there some other function that I need to overload for the same purpose?

Thanks and Regards,
Anup

Comment: This probably is part of Sudden Termination: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSProcessInfo_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000316-SW3 . Try adding NSSupportsSuddenTermination = NO to your Info.plist

Comment: Hi @PierreBernard, unfortunately, the Info.plist is not allowing me to add this to it but I'm trying to figure out a way to add disableSuddenTermination to the ViewController.swift. I'll keep you posted.

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion for a workaround:

Define a variable

```
 var sensorsAreON = false
```

In the function to switch on the sensors add

```
sensorsAreON = true
```

Define a function `switchSensorsOFF()` which switches the sensors off if they are still on. Call this function in `viewWillDisappear()` and `applicationWillTerminate()`

```
  func applicationWillTerminate(notification: NSNotification) {
    switchSensorsOFF()
   // do other stuff
  }

  func viewWillDisappear()
  {
    switchSensorsOFF()
   // do other stuff
  }

  func switchSensorsOFF()
  {
    if sensorsAreON {
      performTheRealFunctionToSwitchSensorsOff()
      sensorsAreON = false
    }
  }
```

If you want to terminate the app when the window is closed, implement the NSApplication delegation method `applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed` and return `true`. Then you could put all your cleaning code into `applicationWillTerminate` rather than `viewWillDisappear`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick help! I have implemented the viewWillDisappear in the ViewController.swift and verified that it does what I want. Your suggestion on applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed is also a very nice tip. But, how do I reference the functions included in ViewController.swift from AppDelegate.swift? There doesn't seem to be a self.window.etc,etc anymore (as it was in Objective-C)!